# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})$

I am trying to evaluate this limit. First I multiplied by the conjugate to obtain: $a_n=\dfrac{-n}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}$

I was able to show the limit by taking $f(x)=a_x$ and then applying l'Hôpital's rule. I was primarily wondering if there is a certain trick that can be used to find the limit without resorting to this.

> \begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty} n(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})=-\infty \end{align}

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or we can look at $n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\geq\dfrac{n}{2\sqrt{n+1}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}}}\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so the limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: As a reality check; how do I justify the last step which says that the limit goes to infinity as n goes to infinity?

Comment: The denominator goes to $2$, while the numerator goes to $\infty$, so the whole thing still goes to $\infty$.

Comment: I thought it only works like that if we know both the limits exist. Doesn't the numerator's limit then not technically exist because its infinity? Sorry for such a nitpicky question...

Comment: As long as it is not of $0\cdot\infty$, you are safe to do that, this can be proved rigorously by $\epsilon$-argument of course.

Answer (score 3):

Start from

$${-n\over \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}={-\sqrt{n}\over 1+\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}}={N\over D}$$

We have $D\to 1$ and $N\to -\infty$